# JavaFX TableView Paginator with Scene Builder

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Can someone give me an example of how to create Tableview with pagination assistance Scene Builder?

Comment: Could you please improve the description of the desired result, since ***pagination assistance*** doesn't ring a bell for me and a web search didn't really help.